# How to automatically deploy a Node-RED instance in Docker (including extra nodes)?

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose, node-red

I'd like to automatically deploy a Node-RED instance using docker-compose.

The goal is to deploy:

- Flows (DONE - by populating `/data/flows.json`)
- Settings (DONE - by populating `/data/settings.js`)
- Login credentials (DONE - settings.js)
- Timezone (DONE - docker-compose.yml)
- Extra nodes (**NOT** done)

I can't figure out how to deploy palettes on first start, essentially it would be enough to run `cd /data; npm install` on first start.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  nodered:
    image: nodered/node-red
    user: root:root             # necessary, otherwise we get 'access denied'
    environment:
      TZ: Europe/Amsterdam
    ports:
      - "1880:1880"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
```

Answer (score 1):

You create your own Docker container that extends the `nodered/node-red` container and include your own `package.json` that has the extra nodes you want to include in the `dependencies` section.

Make sure you add your dependencies to the existing `package.json` file that is included in the base image.

More detailed instuctions can be found in the node-red-docker project on github [here](https://github.com/node-red/node-red-docker/tree/master/docker-custom)

Answer (score 1):

After some research I'd like to propose a simple answer to my question.

Pros:

- Lightweight
- Works without cloning the official image
- Doesn't need a rebuild when dependencies change

Cons:

- I don't like the very last line of my entrypoint.sh (since I had to copy it from the official image)

Modified docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
  nodered:
    image: nodered/node-red
    user: root:root             # necessary, otherwise we get 'access denied'
    entrypoint: /data/entrypoint.sh
    environment:
      TZ: Europe/Amsterdam
    ports:
      - "1880:1880"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
```

/data/entrypoint.sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh

DIR=`pwd`

cd /data
npm install

cd "$DIR"
npm start -- --userDir /data
```

For the sake of simplicity `npm install` is run during each startup since I figured out that it takes close to nothing (time) and it's very useful if I need to modify package.json on-the-fly. It's very easy to make it run only once by `touch`-ing a file and then testing for the presence of the file.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the right place to try and discuss this. But running as root is NOT the right solution to the permissions problem

Comment: I agree on that, however (sadly) the 'root:root' approach seems to be the only known workaround which can be found on Node-RED's Github repo, Issues section, e.g.: https://github.com/node-red/node-red-docker/issues/69.